# how to change WebContent name in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

In one of my friend project he changed eclipse WebContent name to test, in my eclipse if i change that to WebContent its not deploying.

1. how to change the test to normal WebContent?
2. Where to configure WebContent name in eclipse?

Comment: right click on folder --->rename doesnot this work?

Comment: it works but after the app is not deploying. they have hard coded some where with test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the Web Deployment Assembly settings via the [project properties](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user/topics/twprjset.html). These settings are stored in the `.settings\org.eclipse.wst.common.component` XML file.

*This information applies to Eclipse (3.7) Indigo.*